# How does compiler understand the key and value part of an object during casting?

Tags: java, casting

I was going through https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm .
It gives following code

```
1       // Get a set of the entries
2       Set set = hm.entrySet();

3       // Get an iterator
4       Iterator i = set.iterator();

5       // Display elements
6       while(i.hasNext()) {
7           Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
8           System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
9            System.out.println(me.getValue());
10        }
```

I was wondering that in line 7 the coder has done i.next() which returns *java.lang.Object* which has been cast to Map.Entry type.Remember in line 7 *me* variable has pointer to the keys of map that had been defined in earlier lines.
In line 9 we call me.getValue() ,so how does jvm know that a particular value is associated with a particular key?

Comment: No, `me` in line 7 is a _reference_ (you can think of it as a pointer but there's still a difference) to the _next_ entry in the map, i.e. a very specific entry. That entry consists of a key and a value which is why lines 8 and 9 work. Note that line 4 establishes an iterator, line 6 checks if there is one more entry and line 7 gets that entry.

Comment: Btw, since Java 5 (which is very old now) there are generics and maps should not be used without those generics anymore. Hence the code should become `Map<String, Double> hm = new HashMap<>();` (also using the "program to interface" principle) as well as `Set<Map.Entry<String, Double>> set = hm.entrySet(); Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Double>> i = set.iterator(); ... Map.Entry<String, Double> me = i.next();` (note the cast is missing now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For easy understanding I have updated the code.  `i.next()` is saved to Object variable before type casting to `Map.Entry`

```
while(i.hasNext()) {
         Object obj = i.next();
         Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)obj;
         System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
         System.out.println(me.getValue());
      }
```

From the below image captured in debug mode, you can see obj contains key-value before type casting.

[image]

To sum up, `i.next()` is returning a `Map.Entry` but we are storing it in an `Object` Class reference variable because java allows super class reference variable to hold the sub class object and `Object` class is super class to all.

Why typecasting? because we can't invoke sub class methods on a super class variable.

If you want the iterator to return Map.Entry without type casting, declare  Iterator as `Map.Entry` Iterator like this `Iterator<Map.Entry> i`. Happy learning!